# How to Render a transparent Texture in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparent, texture2d, alpha-transparency

for around two days now I am dispairing:

For my current Project im caused to use a Texture(png) with a transparent Part,
while rendering it results not as expected, but with Black pixels, there where they should be transparent...

with blending: Expectable the rest of the texture mixed with the blue Clear color

after researching I came to conclusion that there are three possible issues:

1. (what I thought for most likely) : Its cause of my Shader (maybe because it doesn't multiplies with alpha Value)
2. : Its the blending mode (I used this:
   `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`)
3. : Its the way Im loading the texture(i copied pasted it from my main Source of Information)

Main source of Information: http://androidblog.reindustries.com/android-opengl-es-2-0-shaders-series-002-texture-shaders/

Based on this Site changed my previous Shaders with this:

```
public static final String vs_Image =
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
 "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
 "attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
  "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
  "varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
  "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
  "void main() {" +
  "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
  "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
  "  v_Color = a_Color;" + 
  "}";

public static final String fs_Image =
  "precision mediump float;" +
  "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
  "varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
  "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
  "void main() {" +
  "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ) * v_Color;" +
  "  gl_FragColor.rgb *= v_Color.a;" +
  "}";
```

But in succession all objects rendered with the Program, I created with this shaders weren't shown...

Anyone could say me where is the issue or which steps have to be done to render transparent textures? I would be very thankfull :D

[With a shader doesnt multiplieing with the alpha amount(no Blending): the transparent is rendered as black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3ljY.png)

[The same like picture 1 but with blending[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/444IU.png)

[With the shwon Shader no matter i turn blending on -
no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX2fz.png)

Comment: Did you enable [blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)? -  `GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);`

Comment: In your question is missing a verifiable example. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)